# AWK field variable (e.g. $1) creates new line? Concatenation issue

Tags: bash, unix, awk

```
awk '
 BEGIN {
 FS = ">";
 insertStatement = "Rating:";
}

/<Overall Rating>/{

 insertStatement = insertStatement $2 "percent";
 printf insertStatement;
}
' $file
```

This code produced the following output:

```
percent4
```

Expected:

```
Rating:4percent
```

I am presuming $2 produces a new line? 
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: The fact that the '4' appeared at the end should have shot alarms off to say you are probably dealing with a Windows created file and need to run dos2unix over it first or allow for the extra '\r' as RS

Comment: @grail perfect, thank you! Change RS="\r \r" and it works.

Comment: I would have thought '\r\n', but if it is working that is all that matters :)

Answer (score 2):

`$<n>` (such as `$2`) does not 'create' a new line, and you don't *have* a new line. You apparently have overstriking on the existing line, usually caused by a CR character. You can see this by piping the output through `cat -v` or `sed -n l` or similar.

If your data file contains **CRLF line endings** instead of Unix-standard LF, as is frequently the case for files processed on or even transferred through Windows systems or applications and often the case for files or data downloaded from websites or FTP*/SFTP sites, `awk` does treat the CR characters as the last character of the line and the last character of the last field on the line. If `$2` is the last field on that line, then yes `$2` will include the spurious CR character and **cause this problem**.

Crossdupe: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312446/using-awk-to-make-new-file-results-in-issues-using-1-specific-column-cant-fig

**To fix**:

- get an input file that already has LF not CRLF
- fix the line endings in in the file with the specific `dos2unix` program or any number of equivalents using tools like `tr sed` etc
- remove the CR in awk with `sub(/\r$/,"")` or equivalent